# How to watch for public messages using Discord API?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I followed the OAuth2 instruction to get access to my account:

```js
const oauthResult = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    code,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: `http://localhost:${port}`,
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
});

const oauthData = await oauthResult.json();

const userResult = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
  headers: {
    authorization: `${oauthData.token_type} ${oauthData.access_token}`,
  },
});

console.log(await userResult.json());
```

Now, how do I watch for messages? I want to get notifications about messages containing certain keywords in public channels I'm invited to. I'm ok to use Discor JS, Python or Rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read messagess through the REST API with a user token obtained through OAuth. There are some other ways to accomplish what you want, though:

---

### RPC

[Discord's API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes) does list a `messages.read` scope for OAuth that you might have found, but it is only for [RPC](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc), which is a local way for connecting to a local Discord client running on a computer. This would require your client and the program you're developing to be always running in order for you to get notifications about messages.

You could then use the [GET_CHANNEL](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc#getchannel) command periodically to obtain a list of messages in such channels, and check for new messages.

---

### Gateway

The only way to do this "remotely" without breaking Discord's terms of service is using a bot token to connect to the [gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway) (which is easier to accomplish by using discord.js, discord.py or some other library), and then listening for the `MESSAGE_CREATE` event. This would allow you to receive notifications from Discord whenever new messages are sent. **Be aware that your bot needs to be in the server and have permission to read such messages.**